# Recovered deleted objects in S3 still don't work in Rails CMS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, rails-activestorage

I'm using Rails 5.2.6 with Active Storage and AWS S3 along with Comfortable Mexican Sofa as the CMS. A number of files (images and PDFs) were accidentally deleted recently in S3, but no worries, I had versioning enabled so I just went and deleted those delete markers via the AWS console.

But the images aren't reappearing in the Rails CMS. The list of files is still there, but the images don't load. I had assumed deleting delete markers, without changing anything else, would be the same as reverting to the pre-deletion state and the site would therefor work as though nothing was deleted. But that's clearly not the case. Is there some additional step in Active Storage I must do to reconnect those undeleted assets with my Rails app?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.